# How to query with given parameter in CouchDB?

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I have a chat CouchDB which stores records with following format.

```
    type:"chat",
    email:"p@g.com",
    friendEmail:"m@g.com",
    time: [year,month,date,hour,min,sec];
    msg:"I'm very good",
```

I've created a view like this

```
function(doc) {
    if(doc.type==="chat" && doc.email && doc.friendEmail){
        emit([doc.time,doc.email],doc); 
    }
}
```

My questions is how I can get if I want only chat logs by email "p@g.com"?

Side note: I'm using Cradle & NowJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view you've created allows you to retrieve by time (and rows with the same time will be ordered by email).

To create a view that allows lookup by email;

```
emit(doc.email, doc);
```

and then query with

```
?key=p@g.com
```

Note: In neither case is it necessary to copy the whole document into the view. You could instead do emit(key, null) and add &include_docs=true to your query.

Comment: It really solves my problem. Thank you so much. Can I ask a bonus question? What if I want with "email" OR "friendEmail" value? How can I assign key value for that case?

Comment: Sure, do emit(doc.email, doc); *and* emit(doc.friendEmail, doc), then ?key=foo@foo.com will find all docs where either .email or .friendEmail matches.

Comment: It really helps me Robert. Sincerely appreciate your help from my heart :) Do you mind if I ask one more question :P What i'm trying to do is getting chat logs between two person. With above format, all records of "user1" is called out. I want only between eg, "user1" and "user2". In MySQL, I may write "select * from chats where ((email = user1 AND friendEmail = user2) OR (email = user2 AND friendEmail = user1)). By that way, when user1 or user2 login, both of their chat-logs are nicely shown with chronological order. How may I accomplish that task in CouchDB? Your help means a lot to me :)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, something like: emit([doc.email, doc.friendEmail, doc.time], null); and emit([doc.friendEmail, doc.email, doc.time], null); then query with ?startkey=[user1, user2]&endkey=[user1, user2, {}]

Comment: Do u know u saved my life? You r so awesome :) I've been making love with CouchDB & Node for 3 days but can't find enough examples. Mind sharing where can I read more? Thanks anyway for all of your answers :)